# Php DirectoryIterator load range of files from folder

Tags: php, range, scandir

I am using DirectoryIterator to load mp3 files from directory. I am wondering can I load a certain range? For example retrieve only 10 files? And then on each new request retrieve next 10 and so on.. How could I achieve that? Would I use my own counter or does DirectoryIterator has some option? If I use my own counter, how would I make sure the result in not compromized in some way like maybe files come back sorted differently?

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
foreach ($di as $fileinfo) {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count yourself and work with the methods next() and current(). The end must also check itself with valid().

Foreach always returns all elements from the beginning.

```
$di = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__);

for($i=0; $i<5 AND $di->valid();$i++, $di->next()){
  echo $di->current()->getFilename()."<br>";
}

//next 5 files
for($i=0; $i<5 AND $di->valid();$i++, $di->next()){
  echo $di->current()->getFilename()."<br>";
}
```

Comment: If DI always returns all files from directory, wouldnt it be better to then store all in javascript  array (where I used the anyway), and then manipulate next in javascript when I need them? Why would I use php with next and current instead, what would be the advantage? Or I use use scandir, could I benefit otherwise?

Comment: Your question concerned the DirectoryIterator.
No question, there are simpler solutions.
You can use glob ("*. Mp3") and then split the supplied array with array_chunk() .

Comment: I know how to manipulate array and returned results from php. I was just wondering can I make partial grab of files from directory (to speed up the process if there are lots of files inside). If DI always returns all files, then my guess is that there is no benefit in performance if I fetch all files into javascript and manipulate them from there (instead of calling php again).